# Migrating SVN permissions into GitLab

Tags: git, svn, gitlab

So I work in a research group with people of various programming skill levels. We are trying to migrate from SVN to git (self hosted GitLab was chosen for us we don't have control over that). The issue is that we currently rely on per folder per team member permissions on files do to certain NDA's. What are the options for implementing something like this in git or should we just stick with SVN?

So far we have tired making a submodule for each folder with permissions but this leads to way too may repositories. We've also looked into using git-crypt to implement read permission but it is a bit janky and doesn't address the issue of granular write permissions (which seem to be possible in GitLab under the paid version).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Reading your question, I hardly get an idea what you're asking. You work somewhere and you have programming skills and that doesn't matter at all. You have some solution for whatever you want to do in Subversion which you don't explain and it doesn't work in Git for reasons unknown. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back, [edit] and improve your question.